# Ivy League typeface/font family - Origins and legit sourcing?

Tags: fonts, resource-recommendations, typefaces, licensing, font-licensing

I'm a novice relative to typeface/font family sourcing. A client's style guide specifies the Ivy League typeface. I've spent an unsuccessful hour in online research trying to find the entire font family for purchase, for free, or some combination (i.e., a one-stop shopping site that I can trust).

That hasn't worked, so I also tried searching based on who owns/developed/invented the typeface and came up with confusing results.

Pointers to the Ivy League typeface origins, where to get it, or both are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. I also need to declare myself a novice. I see that a style guide just specifying "the Ivy League" is rather limited. Many typefaces come in versions and in generations and from several providers. You could show your client what happens when you just type "Didot" in (for example MyFonts). Maybe they will let you get in touch with the person who (once) created the style guide or they will give you access to some work which was created earlier, to help track down the specific typeface they want - to match their earlier stuff.

Comment: @MartinZaske - Great suggestion, especially when considering that the company is only a few years old and the style guide itself is unusually small (a scant six pages including the title page, and three of those pages devoted to large graphics of the logo). I.e., they still have much to learn about improving the style guide itself.

Comment: So, if your last comment was not sarcastic, you could even try to move them towards a commercial typeface with reliable sourcing and clear licence-situation. You might find a font which has a very similar look, or have something created/adapted as a custom-job if only a few characters are needed (for a logo or motto).

Comment: @MartinZaske - Was not being sarcastic at all, and am mystified that it might be interpreted that way. Maybe I should have noted that I'm accustomed to seeing style guides of 100 pages or more, so there were items missing that maybe they hadn't considered. Will have that discussion in due time. Thank you for you additional suggestion.

Comment: I had made such a humble contribution and you wrote "great suggestion" and I do not get any body language in writing, so I figured it might be sarcasm. But since I do not like assumptions (nor missunderstandings), I did NOT interpret your comment as sarcastic, I just wrote a short if-clause to be more clear. Also I see now that you are new to typeface-sourcing but not at all new to graphic-design and to seeing style guides. Hope this project turns out great, let us know please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as @MartinZaske suggested in his comment to my original post and was able to obtain the font family. The client is a franchisee and access to fonts and logos are covered in the fees paid to the franchisor.

Having said that, there is no foundry listed in the file properties. But they assure me all is as it should be, so as Yoda would say, "Trust I must."

Answer (score 2):

MyFonts has a typeface called [Player](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/canadatype/player/) which supposedly is a remake of the original Ivy League typeface from the 1970s.